# Take a command sent and split it into multiple variables with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.io

What I'm trying to do is write a bot with discord.io, the problem is, that when I came to making a command to set nicknames, I ran into a problem, I knew that I am supposed to use the `message.substring(1).split(' ');` syntax, but I don't know how to take the now split message string and put the substrings into separate variables. How exactly would I do that? I'm hoping to set/change their nickname to what I set it to using this `?setnick <userID> <nickname to have it set it to>`

Comment: At the very least you need to show what you're expecting to get from your split. What's the end result? If I were you, I'd write code in a totally separate file to practice splitting strings and proof out what you're trying to do before trying to make it work with Discord. You can grab a message string from Discord and use that in your prototype code.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do something like this:

Let's pretend the `message.content` looks like this: `"?setnick 0123 testName"`

```
// first, store message content into small variable (to keep things clean later)
let msg = message.content;

// now pull out the command arguments - everything after the first space in message.content
let argString = msg.substr( msg.indexOf(' ') + 1 );

// argString should be "0123 testName"
// -> now split argString into pieces (id and new nickname)
let argArr = argString.split(' ');

// argArr should be ["0123", "testName"]
// -> now store each argument into its own new variable
let [uid, newNickname] = argArr;
```

Now you have two variables, `uid = "0123"` and `newNickname = "testName"` which you can use.

You probably also want to do add some validation on your `argArr` variable - so if the user adds extra text in the argument, you can either throw an error or add the extra data as the nickname (as examples).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

After you split the message, you'll have an array with all the parts.

```
var message = " part1 part2 part3";
var array = message.substring(1).split(' ');
// array = ["part1", "part2", "part3"]
```

You can access these by using the array's indexes:

```
var part1 = array[0];
// part1 = "part1"
```

Or you can use forEach to do something with each part:

```
array.forEach(x => console.log(x));
// part1
// part2
// part3
```

Comment: would the x be all of the array parts, or the array part that you assigned the array[x]

Comment: The code will run for each part and x will hold the value of each individual part each time the code runs.